# Plotting data and time zones on highcharts react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, next.js

I have an chart component in react. It takes in data that has been pulled from an API. I get an array of objects which returns rows that looks something like this

```
Rows: [
{
    EffectiveTime: "06-Nov-2020 00:00:00",
    FieldName: "GEN_EXP",
    Region: "ALL",
    Value: 3837
},
{
    EffectiveTime: "06-Nov-2020 00:15:00",
    FieldName: "GEN_EXP",
    Region: "ALL",
    Value: 3835
},]
```

In my charts I can plot it fine with the value only, but when I try plotting the time also, I have an issue.

How can I plot my values on the Y axis, my time on the x axis, and have my x axis measuring time between midnight - 23:30 with 2 hour intervals.

This is my react component

```
const LineChart = ({ data, error }) => {
    
    if(error) {
        console.log('Error');
    };

    let d = [];
    let t = [];

    Object.entries(data.Rows).forEach(
        ([key, value]) => {
            d.push(value.Value)
            t.push(value.EffectiveTime)
        }
    );

    const time = t.map(item => {
        const split = item.split(' ')[1];
        return item;
    });


    const options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            scrollablePlotArea: {
                minWidth: 600,
                scrollPositionX: 1
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Wind speed during two days',
            align: 'left'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            max: Date.UTC(2021, 0, 1, 7)
          },
        series: [{
            data: [{
                x: time,
                y: d
            }]
        }],
  
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                turboThreshold: 0,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                lineWidth: 5,
            }
        },
        // tickInterval: markInterval,
        min: 0,
        max: Math.max(d)
    };

    return (
        <HighchartsReact
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            options={options}
        />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your data to the format required by Highcharts (for example an object with `x` - timestamp in milliseconds and `y` - number properties).

```
var data = [{
        EffectiveTime: "06-Nov-2020 00:00:00",
        FieldName: "GEN_EXP",
        Region: "ALL",
        Value: 3837
    },
    {
        EffectiveTime: "06-Nov-2020 00:15:00",
        FieldName: "GEN_EXP",
        Region: "ALL",
        Value: 3835
    }
];

var processedData = data.map(el => ({
    x: new Date(el.EffectiveTime).getTime(),
    y: el.Value
}));

var options = {
    series: [{
        data: processedData
    }],
    ...
}

Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rp1vejku/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data